Is it possible to undo a modifier_map command in xkb?
I want to remap some modifiers on my keyboard. By using xkbcomp :0 /tmp/maps and grepping through /usr/share/X11/xkb I found that modifiers were mapped in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc. I want to remove some of these modifiers,but looking at the docs and he source code for xkbcommong there doesn't seem to be a command to unmap modifiers, unless this undocumented replace keyword does something.
Is it possible to unmap modifiers or do I have to copy-and-modifier the pc symbols file?

Remapping modifiers is reasonably easy with xmodmap. Here are a couple of examples: Caps Lock to Compose, Caps Lock to Hyper. Do remember to keep keysyms and modifier assignments consistent or else strange things will happen.
With XKB, a lot of things require constructing a whole new keymap and loading it. You can construct the keymap based on existing settings. If you want detailed control over individual settings, you can dump the current keymap, rewrite it and load the result. For example, the following untested code should remove any modifier assignment from LWIN (note that it doesn't check whether LWIN is actually mapped to a modifier).
xkbcomp "$DISPLAY" - |
grep -v -E -e '^ *key <LWIN>.*;' -e '^ *modifier_map .*<LWIN>' |
xkbcomp - "$DISPLAY"

Another approach is to construct a keymap from pieces that don't include the modifier mapping that you don't want. It's more complicated if the only thing you want to do is unmap a modifier, but it may be easier overall, depending on what you do. I use this approach. Here's a simplified version of my code that shows how to invert the effect of NumLock: the keypad inserts numbers without Shift when the NumLock modifier is off.
# Configuration section. Empty to keep defaults.
# Otherwise base+file1(partial_section1)+file2(partial_section2)+...
xkb_geometry=
xkb_keycodes=
xkb_layout=
xkb_symbols=
xkb_types=complete+mytypes(invert_numlock)

{
  set setxkbmap
  [ -n "$xkb_geometry" ] && set "$@" -geometry "$xkb_geometry"
  [ -n "$xkb_keycodes" ] && set "$@" -keycodes "$xkb_keycodes"
  [ -n "$xkb_layout" ] && set "$@" -layout "$xkb_layout"
  [ -n "$xkb_symbols" ] && set "$@" -symbols "$xkb_symbols"
  [ -n "$xkb_types" ] && set "$@" -types "$xkb_types"
  "$@" -print
} | xkbcomp -I"$HOME/etc/xkb" - "$DISPLAY"

The complete type comes with XKB. I have a file ~/etc/xkb/types/mytypes with the following contents:
partial xkb_types "invert_numlock" {
  type "KEYPAD" {
    modifiers = Shift+NumLock;
    map[None] = Level2;
    map[Shift] = Level1;
    map[NumLock] = Level1;
    map[Shift+NumLock] = Level2;
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Number";
  };
  //include "extra(keypad)"
};

Plus extra magic not shown here to uncomment the inclusion of extra(keypad) on older systems where that line is needed. The maps shipped with XKB don't change often, but they don't try to preserve backward compatibility for people who aren't satisfied with the predefined options.
Override a few keycodes with XKB and How does xkb compilation work? may be useful as a bit of additional information about XKB.

Thanks for the detailed reply. Unfortunately, I have a nice setup with xmodmap, but it does not seem to work with some "cross platform" apps (e.g. chrome and obsidian). So I'm trying to redefine my keymap in xkb in the hope that this will work with these apps. (I want to do a lot of work with obsidian).

I'm using the xkbcomp approach at the moment. It seems to have picked up some of my xmodmap bindings but not all of them... which is weird. I don't quite understand what that set logic does. A problem I found with setxkbmap was that it was always trying to load the pc symbols which included the modifiers and I couldn't work out how to patch out the rules....
